# \dot Notation not working Latex (overleaf)

Tags: overleaf

I am writing my thesis and anytime I use `\dot{\alpha}` or `\dot{a}` or any variation of `\dot` or `\.` it puts a dot next to (on left side) of the variable

```
•a
```

I have a large file with multiple chapters (I am writing my thesis).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}
```

this is the main document class in the tex file and then chapters are subsequently added.

Each chapter just has

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}
```

I am using `\dot` like this

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:5.1}
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \ddot\alpha \\
    \.q \\
    \ddot \theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\eng{equation}\
```

`\.` is working with `q` but `\dot` is not working with `\alpha` and `\theta`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Are you in math mode when you execute `\dot`, `\ddot`, etc? Please advise. It would be helpful if you provided a compilable example that reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have a large file with multiple chapters ( I am writing my thesis ).


\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}

this is the main document class in the tex file and then chapters are subsequently added
Each chapter just has

\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

I am using \dot like this

\begin{equation} \label{eq:5.1}
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \ddot\alpha \\
    \.q \\
    \ddot \theta 
\end{bmatrix}
\eng{equation}\

Comment: Look at the 10 upvotes for the first comment. Please provide a full buty minimal example we can copy and test as is, so we co not have to guess (that might be wrong).  ``\.`` is a text accent, these cannot be used in math mode, and I get a clear error if I attempt to use it in math mode. Don't you get an error? if not, then again, MWE please.

Comment: There are many, many `Thesis.cls` around the world. Without a pointer to the one you are using and a minimal document, it's impossible to help more than saying that `\dot\alpha` should work in math mode and `\.q` doesn't really.

Answer (score 2):

- you have typo in code (`\eng{equation}` instead correctly `\end{equation}`)
- correct syntax for putting dots above variable is `\dot{q}` or `\ddot{\alpha}` or as note @egreg in his comment below `\dot q` `\dot\apha`. Still `\. q` is wrong syntax
- so if I correctly understood what is your problem, than your equation's code should be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{mathtools} % or amsmath

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:introduction}

    \begin{equation}\label{eq:5.1}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot{\alpha}   \\
    \dot{q}         \\
    \ddot{\theta}
\end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:5.2}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \ddot \alpha    \\
    \dot q          \\
    \ddot \theta 
\end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For document class i Use `book` since I don't know which `Thesis` you use. However, used document class should not influence on appearing of dots (for time derivatives) above variables.

Comment: Based on TeX rules, `\dot\alpha` and `\dot{\alpha}` behave the same (provided `\dot` has a standard definition, which I believe can be assumed).

Comment: Hello. I have tried that but it still doens't work. Is it possible I can link/share my overleaf latex template?

Comment: I tested my answer in Overleaf too and as expected, it works fine. Please provide link to your test in Overleaf.